# Selecting Data in a table based on results from another table

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a *products* table where some of the products are marked as import products. I then have an *orders* table where orders are stored. What I am trying to do is retrieve products from the *orders* table that are only marked as imports in the products table. The code below works when I run it on a local server, but when I upload it to a live server, I am unable to retrieve any data from the orders table with the same code. How can I achieve this?

***sql***

```
  $sellerID = $_SESSION['id'];
  $shops = "SELECT * FROM shops WHERE sellerID = '$sellerID'";
  $shopsResult = mysqli_query($conn, $shops);
  $shopsData = mysqli_fetch_assoc($shopsResult);
  $shop = $shopsData['id'];

  $products = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_import = 'yes' OR shopID = '$shop'";
  $productResult = mysqli_query($conn, $products);
  $prod = mysqli_fetch_assoc($productResult);
  $prodID = $prod['id'];

  $orders = "SELECT * FROM orders WHERE productID = '$prodID'";
  $ordersResult = mysqli_query($conn, $orders);
  echo mysqli_num_rows($ordersResult); //this returns a 0 on the online site.
```

Comment: can you try  log the $orders query what it returns and also log $ordersResult data in server?

Comment: @SenthilnadhanRamasamy it shows no errors. just returns nothing when it's on the live server but on my localhost, using the same code, it retrieves the order from the database

Answer (score -2):

i think you need to review the code in some parts

- i am concerned that you are using very old layer of mysqli querying method which can lead to sql injection exploit so easily. you can use pdo or at least try the sql object oriented way.
- you are using the first match, not all products ids. so on live maybe the first match product doesn't have orders so you will get zero

```
  $sellerID = $_SESSION['id'];
  $shops = "SELECT * FROM shops WHERE sellerID = '$sellerID'";
  $shopsResult = mysqli_query($conn, $shops);
  $shopsData = mysqli_fetch_assoc($shopsResult);
  $shop = $shopsData['id']; // please notice you are getting only the first matching shop

  //i am not sure, should it be OR, i think it should be AND
  $products = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_import = 'yes' OR shopID = '$shop'";
  $productResult = mysqli_query($conn, $products);
  $prod = mysqli_fetch_assoc($productResult);
  $prodID = $prod['id']; //here again you are only getting the first match product id

  //you are selecting all orders which match only one product 
  $orders = "SELECT * FROM orders WHERE productID = '$prodID'";
  $ordersResult = mysqli_query($conn, $orders);
  echo mysqli_num_rows($ordersResult);
```

Comment: how can I make it get all the products instead of one?